# Is it possible to Test iPhone Application on Actual Device rather than Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I wants to test my own application to my actual iPhone Device rather then simulator.

So, is there any chance to do so with ?

I have an apple developer account.. But don't know the procedure, Please help me if u have any solutions..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Log in to http://developer.apple.com/iphone/ with your developer id and password.
Then:

1. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/team/index.action and set up your team.
2. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/certificates/team/index.action to create your certificate
3. Download the certificate you just created and double click on it to run Keychain Access and install it.
4. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/devices/index.action to enter your iPhone's id
5. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/bundles/index.action create an appID
6. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action to download a provisioning profile
7. Drop that provisioning profile onto Xcode
8. Go into your project's info.plist and change your Bundle identifier to be the same as you used for the provisioning profile, minus everything up to the first "."
9. Go into your project's Build Info, and select the appropriate Code Signing Profile
10. I think now you're ready to go.  Select an iPhone Device from the pop-up menu in your main project browser window, plug your iPhone in and let Xcode see it, and then Build and Run.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but as iPhone applications need to be signed - you need to be a paid developer. It is then a case of logging into the portal, assigning a test device, application settings and then downloading a provisioning certificate.

Comment: As i have a standard developer account of $99. Can you please tell me the further procedure for certification ?

Answer (score 2):

The procedure is cumbersome, however it is very well documented.

You need to create your Developer Certificate and a Certificate for your software projects.

Go to http://developer.apple.com/iphone/, log in and click iPhone Developer Program Portal on the right side. You will find a "launch Assistant" there that will guide you through the next steps. It's pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the [iPhone Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/), which is $99 for the Standard Program, $299 for the Enterprise Program.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that i have a developer account of $99. Please suggest me further procedure..