# iPhone SDK: How can I test my app on an actual device?

Tags: iphone

I have built an iPhone app that I need to test on an actual device. How do I get the app onto the device? I have an Apple Developer account.

Also, I will need to distribute the binary to some of our testers. How can I get them a copy of the app?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558585/is-it-possible-to-test-iphone-application-on-actual-device-rather-than-simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pay the $99 to Apple and get a developers certificate to sign your app to install it on an actual device.

Comment: The OP says (s)he has it: *I have an Apple Developer account.*

Comment: just having an ADC account is NOT the same thing as paying the $99 developer fee and getting a certificate

Answer (score 2):

Use the tutorial in Apple iPhone Developer Program (the Development Provisioning Assistant available from [iPhone Developer Program Portal main page](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action)).

It will guide you through the process of creating app identifiers, certificates, provisioning profiles, it has screenshots etc.

And also, please consider using Google/search... Terms to look for may include e.g. "ad-hoc distribution".

Comment: Thanks for the link but please leave the scolding for your children. Telling someone to google is like telling them to breathe. There are tons of Apple developer links on google.

Comment: Actually, you deserved it. First few hits are abundant with knowledge, including a hit on this site... http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=iphone+app+actual+device

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this is helpful but you might not have thought about it as it seems obvious to me at least. I am guessing but i imagine that you can probably get an iphone software emulator which you can run the program through for testing. good luck. Just had a look try this was the first search return

http://iphonetester.com/

Scratch this although might be useful the guy above hit the proverbial on the head.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/

Comment: The dev toolkit comes with a software one; he wants to try it on a real phone.  Also, your link doesn't actually run apps, it just shrinks websites.