# Can I have multiple developers test my iPhone/iPad app if I create an Individual account, instead of a Company Account?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

i'm wishing to try some iPhone/iPad development with [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) (<3 .NET) and the first step is to create an account/enrol in the Apple Development Program.

The first thing they ask me is if this will be an individual or a company. First up, this is just myself and a mate .. so we don't really have some official company set up etc (please -> any suggestions to do this will be met on deaf ears. If our R&D work out - THEN we'll get that sorted).

BUT - we would like to make it so myself, my mate AND our family/friends can test out our R&D effort - say .. 1 dev, 1 UI guy and 4 or 5 family/friends.

What type of account should I have?

I've read some other SO posts that it's [possible to have other people test out apps on the actual device(s) with some magic certificate stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558585/is-it-possible-to-test-iphone-application-on-actual-device-rather-than-simulator) ... but I just want to make sure I get the correct account set up.

Cheers :)

Comment: should it be on programmers.stackexchange? +1 for good question

Comment: I don't think it needs to be moved.  It is not subjective.  It could be argued that it is not a "programming question", but who other than a programmer would ask it or answer it?

Comment: If you don't have a company you can't get the company account anyway.

Comment: Questions like this are why [the App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) needs your support!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do ad-hoc distribution to up to 100 devices using an individual developer account.

There isn't any difference between an individual account and a company account in terms of what you can do to develop, test, and distribute apps.  The only difference is that with a company account, there is a Team Leader who can add other developers to the account and manage their capabilities, but that has nothing to do with distributing the app.

Comment: so does this mean that the individual will be considered the Team Leader role and he/she will have to log in to control all the (upto 100) devices, etc? Can't see how anyone else can control it - it is in individual account after all...

Comment: Correct.  With an individual account, there is only one user associated with the account.  That user can assign devices, create and download distribution profiles, and do all the other necessary stuff.

Comment: Adding to his question, is this 100 device limit applicable to per app-id or per developer account?

Comment: The 100-device limit is per account. Note that for a company-owned account, the 100-device limit is for the whole company, no matter how many developers are associated with that account.