# apple certificate for testing starling games

Tags: ios, starling-framework

I am wondering how i can test my applications on a real iPad.
I have bought an apple developer id and i would like to do some tests on my iPad.

The problem is that i need to register my application, need to enter screenshots and icons, description and how much it will cost, etc...

The problem is that i don't know all this stuff yet. I just want to create a certificate that i can use for testing purposes.

Does anyone know what's the easiest way to get one from apple?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Test iPhone Application on Actual Device rather than Simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558585/is-it-possible-to-test-iphone-application-on-actual-device-rather-than-simulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not need to enter screenshots, icon and everything. Just go to the "iOS Provisioning Portal" in your developer account and then launch the "Development Provisioning Assistant". Follow the steps and you will be on your way :)